# Two Font Sizes In Same Table Cell

Tags: css, html-table

I am trying to have two different Font Sizes in the same Table `th` cell

My code is as below but does not appear to work i.e. the (Frm) stays at font 14

Please help

```
 echo "<th width='70%' style='background-color:#FFD8D8;font-size:14px' colspan=\"14\"><left>".$startlocation."<style='font-size:8px'>"."(Frm)"."</left></th>";
```

Comment: You could always wrap some of the text you want to appear smaller in a `<small>` tag.

Comment: Remove the `<left>` element. Also sad you picked vacsora's answer as the correct, since I was first and my answer is much better. Looking into HTML tags is your next quest.

Comment: Hi Snorlax. Understood. Have given up vote now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no such element called `<left>`. What I would recommend you do, is add classes to your elements instead of using inline styling through `style=`.

```
th {
    width: 70%;
    background-color: #FFD8D8;
} 
.left {
    font-size: 8px;
}
.right {
    font-size: 14px;
}
```

Then you can add a `<span>` tag around your text, which can look something like this as your final code:

```
echo "<th colspan=\"14\"><span class=\"left\">".$startlocation."</span><span class=\"right\">(Frm)"."</span></th>";
```

I'm not sure what your other text is inside the `<th>` element, but doing what I did will solve it. It's also best practise to use classes and IDs instead of inline styling, as it's easier to change in the future.

EDIT: If you absolutely need to to inline styling, this will work:

```
echo "<th colspan=\"14\"><span style=\"font-size:14px\">".$startlocation."</span><span style=\"font-size:8px\">(Frm)"."</span></th>";
```

Comment: @user2635961 You should select it as the correct answer, because I fixed your issue first and it's the most correct.

Comment: I see your point that I seem to have 'made up' a left tag (I am a beginner). Will change the tick but have given an upvote against vascoras comment  as I did see it first.

Answer (score 0):

Insert `<span>` like this:

```
...$startlocation."<span style='font-size:8px'>"."(Frm)"."</span></left></th>"
```

so that you can specify style of *some* *element* the way you tried.

Comment: Hi Vacsora . Your solution works for me. Not sure why you have a down vote. I give you a tick

Comment: @vacsora: There is nothing called a left-tag in HTML, therefore your code won't really work. My solution is a much, much better one, because that is how you would normally do. Inline styling is dead and should be avoided at all cost.

Comment: @Snorkax, I must admint you put a nice effort in formulating your detailed answer while I merely constructed a quick solution of minimal intrusion to existing code. But that's no reason and rude to downvote a fellow answer, especially when you never heard of registering new elements!

Comment: @vacsora I have heard of custom elements and how they are legal, but not unless they become a standard in the biggest browsers, nobody should go create them. It's bad practise for a new programmer, which OP apparently is. Your code surely will work, just like mine will, but I posted mine first and it's more correct :) Also, downvote is probably because it's bad. Just because it works, doesn't mean it's good.